# Laravel 5.6.5 relationship executing wrong query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

As you can see on the following image my laravel relation between shoporder and shoporderroutingstepplans is not as it has to be. 
[image]

I have no idea what I exactly did wrong so I hope someone can help me out. In the code beneath I have left some fields out of the code to make it more legible.

```
class shoporder extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

    protected $fillable = [
        'CADDrawingURL',
        'ID',
        'Costcenter',
        'CostcenterDescription',
        'Costunit',
        'CostunitDescription',
        'Created',
        'Creator',
        'CreatorFullName',
        'Description',
        'ShopOrderParent',
        'ShopOrderParentNumber',
        'ShopOrderRoutingStepPlanCount',
        'Status',
        'SubShopOrderCount',
    ];

    public function shopOrderRoutingStepPlans() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\shopOrderRoutingStepPlan', 'ShopOrder', 'ID');
    }
}

class ShopOrderRoutingStepPlan extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
    public $table = "shoporderroutingstepplans";
    protected $fillable = [
        'Account',
        'ID',
        'AccountName',
        'AccountNumber',
        'AttendedPercentage',
        'Backflush',
        'Created',
        'Creator',
        'CreatorFullName',
        'Description',
        'ShopOrder',
    ];

    public function shopOrder() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\shopOrder', 'ShopOrder', 'ID');
    }
}
```

This is the code Im executing to get the relations of 1 shoporder in the controller.

```
$orders = shopOrder::find('0600959e-6b92-4135-8ea8-1fa2fd92a916')->shopOrderRoutingStepPlans()->get();
```

In the shoporder migration I defined the primary key:

```
$table->string('ID')->unique();
$table->primary('ID');
```

In the shoporderroutingstepplans migration I defined the foreign key as followed.

```
$table->string('ID')->unique();
$table->primary('ID');

$table->foreign('ShopOrder')
      ->references('ID')
      ->on('shoporders');
```

Comment: is `ShopOrder` a column name??

Comment: In ShopOrderRoutingPlanSteps shoporder is a culumn name that has the ID of an ID from the shoporder table

Comment: may be i am wrong but i don't see one name `ShopOrder`

Comment: Sorry I removed some fields because it are like 70 fields but I removed the shoporder field also, I will edit the post.

Comment: You're protecting your `$primaryKey = id` however you're using `find()` to search for `shopOrder`... `find()` can only be utilised for the primarykey therefore `ID` only.

Comment: @iJokerAssassin We do not add `[solved]` to question titles here on the stackexchange sites. Instead, please click the appropriate button to accept an answer. If no one's answer is what solved your problem, please post the solution you found as an answer, and then accept it yourself. This will allow future users to see the solution to this problem, which is a primary main goal of this website.

Answer (score 0):

You must switch the order of the last two parameters:

From

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\shopOrderRoutingStepPlan', 'ShopOrder', 'ID');
```

To

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\shopOrderRoutingStepPlan', 'ID', 'ShopOrder');
```

The parameters are

1. model,
2. name of column in the linked model,
3. name of column in *this* model.

Comment: It executes this query: select * from `shoporderroutingstepplans` where `shoporderroutingstepplans`.`ID` is null and `shoporderroutingstepplans`.`ID` is not null

That is still wrong to get the linkend shoporderroutingstepplans from a shoporder